# Java confusion on fundamentals on double and integer and conversions

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types

I am practicing in an automatic judge for algorithm in one of the carreer sites and I have the following question.
In one of the puzzles the question is to find the median of 2 sorted arrays and the signature of the method to implement is:

```
public double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int B[])
```

I written the code and some of the tests failed.
Looking at the results though the failures reported are as follows:

```
Input       Output  Expected    
[], [1]      1.0    1    
[2], []      2.0    2
```

It seems I am rusty on the fundamentals.

My question: How can it expect an `1` or `2` and reject `1.0` if the method returns a 
`double`?
My snippet of code on the calculation of merge is:

```
 if(array.length %2 == 0){

     return (array[middle] + array[middle - 1])/(double)2;    
 }
 else{
      return (double)array[middle];

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your tests?

Comment: What do you mean?It is an automatic judge site.Do you mean the link for the site?

Comment: It sounds like their error, not yours - a link might be helpful to confirm.

Comment: And the code printing the output is not something you uploaded?

Comment: @The Nail:The part of the code that returns the median is the snippet in the OP.The screenshot is the results that came out

Comment: If the rows in that screenshot all describe calls to the same method, the test seems to be wrong. It's generally true that `1.0 != 1` but a method can't return a `double` if the result isn't integer and an `int` if it is. Are you passing the return value to the test as `double` or are you converting them into `String` (or print them out)?

Comment: @user384706 what I mean is: is the I/O handling part of your submitted program? Or is the judge calling `findMedianSortedArrays`? This is not stated in the OP.

Comment: @biziclop:The calls are only to the same method and the result is returned by the snippet in the OP

Comment: @TheNail:There is no I/O on my part.The judge is calling the method directly (like junit I guess)

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I think it's indeed an error in the judge code.

Comment: I think the judge compares the String output, and some format setting (locale?, java version?) causes a difference between ".0" and "".

Comment: Are you sure the return type of the method shall be double? What about Number? then you return a Double or Integer as your case.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh:I have put the method declaration in OP

Comment: FYI, this is the link: http://www.leetcode.com/onlinejudge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error in the judge. If I go to [the site](http://www.leetcode.com/onlinejudge), select 'Java' and fill in the following Java implementation (just filling in one line, the `return 0;`:

```
public class Solution {
    public double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int B[]) {
        // Start typing your Java solution below
        // DO NOT write main() function
        return 0;
    }
}
```

the report states `output: 0.0` for all cases.

The C++ equivalent does not seem to suffer from the same problem. If I fill in this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int m, int B[], int n) {
        // Start typing your C/C++ solution below
        // DO NOT write int main() function
        return 0;
    }
};
```

then the report states `output: 0` for all cases.